# Opening webcam in docker container with python (cv2.VideoCapture) on a windows host machine

Tags: python, windows, docker, opencv, centos

I'm running docker toolbox on a Windows host machine. I've installed opencv trough `pip install opencv-contrib-python`, this was succesful. Now when I go to my CentOS Docker container with `docker exec -it centos /bin/bash`, after I type `python` and `import cv2` in my python interpreter. I try to create a video capture object `CapDev = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, and it returns the error `VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0`. When I try with index -1 it says: `VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device` 
 What is causing this problem? Is it because of the windows host not allowing the docker container to open the camera, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing this problem? Is it because of the windows host not allowing the docker container to open the camera, or is it something else?

Sort of. Since Docker works with containers, the container you are running does not include the webcam of your laptop. I have searched far & wide, but it doesn't seem easy to solve this issue through Docker on windows.

If you are on linux it would be as simple as adding `--device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0` to your docker command. Windows seems to make it more complicated! I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/hardware-devices-in-containers) which looked helpful, but has not solved the problem for me yet since I cannot switch to windows containers. If you are able to switch to windows containers, this might be your solution!